# Cannot make a static reference to a non static Field

Tags: java, reference, static

Iam trying to create classes and have been partly succesfull. But when I try and create stuff in my `main method` I get these errors on pretty much everything I do. If I instead create this stuff in other methods and then call them from my main method, it works.

BUT thats not what Iam supposed to do, so I need to fix it so the stuff that are in the main method works. The first error I get is when I try and create the object turtle t1 in my main object, I get the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Ystart`

```
import java.util.Random;
import se.lth.cs.window.SimpleWindow;
public class Racetrack {
Random rand = new Random();
int i = 0;
int x;
int Ystart;
int Ygoal;
int RaceTrack;
//SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(500, 500, "22niggs");



public static void main(String[]args) {
    SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(500, 500, "Angels");

    Racetrack race = new Racetrack(100,400);
    race.draw(w);
    Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,50,Ystart);
    Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w,400,Ystart);
    t1.penDown();
    t2.penDown();
    while(i==0){
    x=rand.nextInt(10); 
    t1.forward(x);
    x = rand.nextInt(5);
    t2.forward(x);
    SimpleWindow.delay(100 );
    }

}

    public Racetrack(int Ystart, int Ygoal){ //KONSTRUKTOR
    this.Ystart =Ystart;
    this.Ygoal = Ygoal; 


    }
    public void draw(SimpleWindow w){

    w.moveTo(50, Ystart);
    w.lineTo(450, Ystart);
    w.moveTo(50, Ygoal);
    w.lineTo(450, Ygoal);

    }
    public void RacingEvent(Racetrack track, Turtle t1, Turtle t2){


    }
```

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the relevant language.

Comment: Paste the title of your question in the google search field, hit enter, and read one of the hundreds of results you'll get. Hint: you can't get what's inside a box without the box.

Comment: @JBNizet, alternatively, while composing the question, look at all the duplicates that appear below that are intended to help avoid asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main is static, i.e. there is only one for the entire class, and Ystart is not static, and created to each object.
Then, when you are trying to access Ystart from main, the question is-Ystart of what instance? Since there is no good answer, it makes a compilation error.

You can mark Ystart as static if you want to use it in the main.

Comment: "Then, when you are trying to access Ystart from main, the question is-Ystart of what instance?" Shouldent I be able to write this.Ystart then?

Comment: @user2779497 Yes. each object/instance of the class has its own variable called Ystart. You must refer to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It means you cannot refer to an instance fields without an instance.  In your cases the simplest solution is to

- create an instance to use
- make the field static.  I wouldn't prefer this option.

try

```
Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,50,race.Ystart);
Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w,400,race.Ystart);
```

I would make your random number generator `static` however as there is little value having one per instance.

Answer (score 0):

A static method or field exists as part of a class and independently of an instance of that class. A non-static method or field is dependent on the existence of such an instance. So you can call a non-static method on an object, e.g. `race.draw()` while you can call a static method from the class, e.g. `Racetrack.main(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});`.